# Consequences of having an external signal connected to an output of a LVDS Receiver?

Tags: input, receiver, lvds

I am trying to debug an issue with an LVDS receiver on a fellow colleagues board. They are using an LVDS differential pair from an FPGA to control a reset line on a MPU on their board. For debugging purposes, they've also included a connection for a programming header to the output of the receiver's line. The LVDS Receiver they are using is the [SN65LVDS4RS](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/sn65lvds4.pdf?ts=1637045022444) from TI.  See schematic below:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fP4ZdG.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

They were noticing that the receiver output wasn't toggling when they were toggling the LVDS lines. I've probed the differential lines and I'm seeing the threshold requirements for the differential input voltage changing, so I should be seeing the output toggle either high or low.

Before I looked into this, I was told that they had connected the debug header to an external programming device that sent 1.8V into the receivers output line. Also, when they did this, they weren't connected to the FPGA, so there was never an input on the LVDS receiver. When using the debug programmer, they were able to toggle the reset line btw the header and past the buffer. Based off of what they've told me, I'm afraid that they might've damaged the receiver output line by sending an input from the header to the output of the receiver. Is that the most likely cause of this issue?

Comment: Is R2 (debug header resistor) zero ohms? It is hard to tell from the picture. If so ... maybe they blew the receiver output R.

Comment: R2 is a 0 Ohm resistor